# Redux-saga: axios is not working but fetch() does

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-saga

I have been trying to use **axios** to fetch data by making an `yield call()` through **workerSaga**. I was never able to update the state after fetching the data.

I saw [this](https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/make-your-first-call-to-api-using-redux-saga-15aa995df5b6) tutorial from 2018 that uses a different mechanism. It uses `yield fetch()`.

My approach with **axios**:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeLatest('GET_NEWS', workerSaga);
}

function fetchNews(){
    return axios ({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&apiKey=API_KEY'
    });
}

function* workerSaga() {
    try{
        const resp = yield call(fetchNews);
        const article = resp.articles;

        yield put({ type: 'NEWS_RECEIVED', news: article });
    }
    catch (error){
        yield put({ type: 'NEWS_FETCH_ERROR', error });
    }
}
```

Here everything seems right, the data is fetched (seen in **redux devtools**) but the state fails to update, i.e., the state remains `null`.

The other approach from 2018:

```
function* fetchNews() {
    const json=yield fetch('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&apiKey=API_KEY')
        .then(response => response.json(), );

    yield put({ type: "NEWS_RECEIVED", json: json.articles, });
}

function* workerSaga()  {
    yield takeLatest('GET_NEWS', fetchNews)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([workerSaga(), ]);
}
```

It works flawlessly.

What could be the reason that the former axios one is not working?

Comment: Does it work if you do `axios({ ... }).then(res => res.data)`?

Comment: No i haven't. Please help with the syntax, I am  quite new.

Comment: Isn't the next const `const article` serving the purpose?

Comment: In the axios version's `fetchNews`, I mean.

Comment: `const article = resp.data.articles;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got two correct solutions in the comments but they didn't explain why those work.

The problem is that the return values from `fetch` and `axios` are different (this is why I love typescript -- you would have noticed the difference).

The response returned by `fetch` has a method called `.json()`.  You call `res => res.json()` to get the contents of the response.

The response returned by `axois` has already parsed the JSON for you (depending on your config).  The contents are stored in a property of the response called `data`.

You are currently trying to get `.articles` from the response object, but you need to be getting it from the `.data` property.  There are two ways that you can do this.

1. You could modify the `fetchNews` function so that it returns just the data, as suggested by @cbr

```
function fetchNews(){
    return axios ({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&apiKey=API_KEY'
    }).then( resp => resp.data );
}
```

2. You could modify your `workerSaga` to access the articles from the right path, as suggested by @Aleksey L.

```
      const resp = yield call(fetchNews);
      const article = resp.data.articles;
```

Comment: Putting the `.data` keyword at `resp.data.articles` made it to work. BTW, what does it do?

Comment: `console.log` your `resp` and check out what it looks like.  `data` is just a property on the object, but it is the property where axios puts all of the data.  The other properties on `resp` are information about the request itself like the headers and the config.  You'll see that `resp.data` contains the values that you thought `resp` would contain (`articles`, etc.).